# Stripe Firestore Swift CheckoutViewController not loading ERROR 401

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

==============

I've recently been trying to implement `Stripe` into my IOS (Swift) app using Firebase, Firestore und Cloud Functions.

But for some reason I'm getting this error when loading the CheckoutViewController:

> Response Status Code Was Unacceptable: 401.

I've looked through pretty much all the documentation Stripe has put out on this topic and watched Videos that I could find, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdszUvzroxQ)

That's my swift code:

```
func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock)
{
    let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
        "api_version": apiVersion,
        "customer_id": "cus_IDOFEXISTINGCUSTOMER"
        ])
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { responseJSON in
            switch responseJSON.result
            {
            case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String: AnyObject], nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            }
    }
}
```

And Thats my index.js file for Firebase:

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_MYSECRETKEY');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();


// Express
app.post('/ephemeral_keys', (req, res) =>
{
  const stripe_version = req.body.api_version;
  if (!stripe_version)
  {
    res.status(400).end();
    return;
  }
  // This function assumes that some previous middleware has determined the
  // correct customerId for the session and saved it on the request object.
  stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: req.body.customer_id},
    {stripe_version: stripe_version}
  ).then((key) => {
    res.status(200).json(key);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).end();
  });
});
```

I was expecting my `CheckoutViewController` to be able to load and not get this error.

If my question is missing anything or you need additional information to solve this problem please let me know.